# Joomla 3.x: Combine Category with Tag in blog-view

Tags: php, joomla, tags, overriding

I need to view articles from a selected category with certain Tag(s).
What I've done so far is to override the XML-file (Blog.xml).

I've added:

```
<!-- Add fields to the request variables for the layout. -->
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="request">

        <field 
            name="show_tag_combi" 
            type="tag"              
            label="COM_TAGS_FIELD_TAG_LABEL"
            description="COM_TAGS_FIELD_SELECT_TAG_DESC"
            custom="deny"
            required="true"
            multiple="true"
        />

    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Now I'm able to select the tags I want.

The question is, how do I add its value in my blog-view (Blog.php).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".